# How to Run Multiple Workers In ODOO?

Tags: odoo

I have to check my module in multiple Workers environment and How to check server load in ODOO.

Comment: May be, using manual script you can create multiple requests. Just write a script that may create hundreds of users and using [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html), you can check loading time of any method, operation etc.

Comment: can you give me a this type of script link or example?

Answer (score 4):

I am not quite sure what you mean.

If you mean how to run multiple workers in Odoo, specify "workers=4" in your configuration file and you are good to go.  There are some other settings you can use to set hard and soft limits on memory and CPU time and things like restarting workers after a number of requests - have a look in config.py.  Note the workers option is only available under Unix; another reason to avoid deploying on windows.

If you want to tell if you are running under multiple workers.

```
from openerp.tools import config
worker_count = config["workers"]
```

Comment: where is this config file on odoo 9.0? could you extend your explanation and give more details for new users? Thanks.

Comment: with --config argument you can load config from any location, example /usr/bin/odoo --config=/etc/odoo/odoo.conf

Answer (score 1):

I have faced problem for runnig multiple worker on odoo , for that I have searched little and found that there is one parameter "workers"
in config file.

set "workers = #number_of_worker"

ex:

```
workers = 5
```

I am not sure but , It might be helpful and solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you Need to start multiple worker, for that you need to setup  a web server , apache or nginx.

I Prefer using apache with mod wsgi using multiple worker as per my server CPU, setting worker is depends on your CPU you suing.

**you need to check  tutorial of odoo with apache and wsgi using  2 workers**: [odoo apache2 ubuntu](https://youtu.be/s0BD0YFonDE)